# One server block for domain, another server block for IP of same server

Tags: nginx

I'm using nodejs with nginx as my reverse proxy. In my nginx config I have a server block that is targeted when a client accesses my website via domain name:

```
server {
     root /var/www/html;
     index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
     server_name example.com, www.example.com;

     location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

 listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
 include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
 ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
     if ($host = www.example.com) {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     }  


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com, www.example.com;
    return 404;

}
```

So the above config works fine. But sometimes I need to hit an endpoint on my remote nodejs server by connecting to that server via IP address, and I want to do it securely. So I made a self signed cert on the remote server, and I added another server block like so:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name 149.154.150.134;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert/privkey.pem;

    location / {
            allow 214.107.49.66;
            deny all;
    }
```

}

But nginx always seems to issue the let's encrypt cert, even when I try accessing the server via IP address. I confirmed this when I use this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect 149.154.150.134:443
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx uses [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI) to select the appropriate `server` block by `server_name` when these blocks share the same IP address and port.

To test your server using `openssl s_client` with SNI, you need to provide a server name using the `-servername` parameter.

For example:

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.0.2.1:443 -servername 192.0.2.1
```

In the absence of a `-servername` parameter, Nginx will direct the request to the [default server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) which will be the first `server` block in your configuration with the correct `listen` directive, or the `server` block explicitly marked with the `default_server` option.

---

Also, note that the [`server_name` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) accepts a space separated list of host names - **not** comma separated. For example:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```